# Kivy Black Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I install kivy on my windows 10, set the environment variable to KIVY_GL_BACK = angle_sdl2. but got black screen after running the code

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username:"))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password:"))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginApp().run()
```

I expected the result to be a login form. It not showing any errors

Comment: Do any of the kivy examples work for you?

Comment: I tried in my environment and it shows the login and password. I just did not set the KIVY_GL_BACK = angle_sdl2